# Approximation of integration by simple functions.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f: \Omega\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue integrable function. Does 
>   $$
> s_n=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{k}{2^n}\lambda\left\{\frac{k}{2^n}<f\leq \frac{k+1}{2^n}\right\}
> $$
>   converges absolutely and
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\int_\Omega f\,d\lambda?
> $$

For the case $\Omega=[0,1]$, I have proved that the above is true. For example, suppose $f$ is non-negative. Then

$$
\int f\,d\lambda\geq s_n,
$$
$$
\int f\,d\lambda-s_n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_{\frac{k}{2^n}<f\leq\frac{k+1}{2^n}}\left(f-\frac{k}{2^n}\right)\,d\lambda\leq \frac{1}{2^n}\lambda([0,1]).
$$
Hence the above goes to zero when $n$ goes to infinity.

How about the case $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$? I meet some difficulties in this situation. Thanks.

Comment: No it doesn't for a silly reason: $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=-\dfrac1{1+x^2}$ then for all $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ (and case $k=-1$), $\lambda\left\{-\dfrac1{2^n}<f\leq0\right\}=+\infty$, and $s_n=-\infty$.